# pandoc doesn't text-wrap code blocks when converting to pdf

Tags: pdf, pandoc, pdflatex, xelatex

I'm using pandoc with xelatex engine to convert markdown to pdf. I'm running pandoc like this:

```
pandoc -s 'backbone-fundamentals'.md -o 'backbone-fundamentals'.pdf \
    --title-prefix 'Developing Backbone.js Applications' \
    --normalize \
    --smart \
    --toc \
    --latex-engine=`which xelatex`
```

If a code line is longer than the pdf document width it just gets cutoff. Is there anyway to have pandoc text wrap long code lines?

Comment: This is also a question about wrapping inline code for example long paths or urls which of course can make sense.

Comment: This question is answered here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179926/34551 in a positive way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not having the text wrapped is (part of) the point of code blocks. As far as I know, the only way to wrap the code is manually. For most languages, not exceeding a certain line length is considered good style anyway.

If your lines are length-limited but still too long for your LaTeX-generated pdf, consider reducing the  font size for code blocks. For this you need to change the LaTeX template used by pandoc. A look at this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133442/38399) to "How to set font size for all verbatims in Beamer presentation?" should get you started.

Comment: There is really no way to automatically warp the lines that are too long in code blocks?

Comment: @pimpampoum Since the rendering is done by LaTeX, I guess there might be some way to do so. But I suspect it might necessitate hacking LaTeX, which I don't know anything of. You might want to ask on tex.SE whether knows how to make the `verbatim` environment break lines, and then put that code into the pandoc template.

Comment: I use Pandoc for md -> html and then wkhtmltopdf for html -> pdf just because the LaTeX issues are too much to deal with. What I found is that Pandoc inserts `<style type="text/css">code{white-space: pre;}</style>` in the HTML file's head, and so overriding it with CSS doesn't work. Since I use a script to run all this, I just strip the style out with a sed command.

Comment: `pre, code { white-space: pre-wrap !important; }` worked for me.  But if you're using `.numberLines` the numbers will be off after wrapping.

Comment: When you say wrap the code manually, do you mean just inserting a newline?  For me LaTeX formats the first element of the next line as green, so it doesn't look wrapped...it looks like the start of a new line

Comment: @user766353 you may [replace the HTML template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/User-contributed-templates) for removing the inline style for the `code` tag.

Comment: @A. Dona "For most languages, not exceeding a certain line length is considered good style anyway". Sure it is, but I don't want the LaTeX page width to be dictating what that line length should be.

Answer (score 35):

If you have a recent installation of LaTeX that includes the [fvextra](https://ctan.org/pkg/fvextra) package, then there is a simple solution, recently [suggested by jannick0](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4302#issuecomment-360669013).

Modify your [YAML header options](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block) to include

```
\usepackage{fvextra}
\begin{Highlighting}[breaklines,numbers=left]
```

and compile with xelatex.

For instance,

```
---
header-includes:
 - \usepackage{fvextra}
 - \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}
---

~~~~~{.java}
this is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long line which is broken
~~~~~~
```

when compiled with

```
pandoc input.md --pdf-engine=xelatex -o output.pdf
```

gives [image]

If you had the `.numberLines` option, i.e.,

```
---
header-includes:
 - \usepackage{fvextra}
 - \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}
---


~~~~~{.java .numberLines}
this is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long line which is broken
~~~~~~
```

then the same command would produce

[image]

Comment: Good to know, thanks :) Are the original line numbers (if shown) preserved?

Comment: thank you! I am creating some 2pdf scripts based on this. Is there a way to specify the line width before breaking the line? It seems to be extremely conservative compared to the page size. I have a font size that can handle 80 characters but it seems to break at 60.

Comment: to answer my own question, add `\usepackage[textwidth=6in]{geometry}`

Comment: Thanks @Clément,

Do you know of a way to allow linebreaks anywhere? I have a dynamically markdown document which tends to have very long strings that I also would like to be wrapped....

Comment: @ajendrex There should be a way with the `breakanywhere` option of `fvextra`. Try adding `breakanywhere` after `breaklines`, i.e., replace ` - \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}` by ` - \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,breakanywhere,commandchars=\\\{\}}`, and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @ajendrex Indeed… I don't know the solution to your issue. I'll let you know if I find out how to do it. You could open another question on this website, or at https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4302#issuecomment-360669013

Comment: Is there a way to do this with R Markdown styled blocks? E.g. ````{shell}`? For some reason I'm not getting wrapped or colored output, though it is styled as monospaced code text.

Comment: @Leo Ask with details in a different question and let me know here, and I'll have a look. Based on your comment, I have no idea what it is that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Additional definition is should be added to work with the languages that do not have the corresponding highlighting: for example, plain text (`\`\`\`text`): `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer instead! Works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: `xelatex` is not mandatory for me, at least when using the class `scrartcl`.